# h:commandButton does not call a js function in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a `<commandButton>` the PrimeFaces should call a javascript junction. It works in Firefox but it does not work in Chrome simpleste does not call the function which can be causing this? Really no idea of what can be. I have a `<commandButton>` the PrimeFaces should call a javascript junction. It works in Firefox but it does not work in Chrome simpleste does not call the function which can be causing this? Really no idea of what can be. I have on another page extamente the same case and it works.

JS

```
function atualizarSelect(){
    update();       
    $('#j_idt31:voucherBeanVoucherVeiculo').load('search.xhtml');
    self.close();
}
```

My commandButton

```
<div class="buttons">
    <p:commandButton id="js"  onclick="atualizarSelect()" value="#{msg['btn-save']}" />
    <h:commandButton onclick="self.close()" value="#{msg['btn-cancel']}" />
    <p:remoteCommand id="update" name="update" actionListener="#{veiculoBean.updateModal()}"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume, you added another Element in the xhtml-markup of the page in question. This will cause the (auto-)generated id to be different (the `j_idt_31`) - When you try to reference elements from within (plain) javascript, make sure they have a `static` id assigned in the xhtml-markup - like your `voucherBeanVoucherVeiculo`.

Comment: What is happening is that the commandButton draws js function but the `update ()` is not executed. `Update` is a remoteCommand Button of Primefaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried it on Chrome 39.0.2171.95 and it works great!
Probably there is a problem with auto-generated id as suggested by [dognose comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449437/hcommandbutton-does-not-call-a-js-function-in-chrome#comment43346524_27449437).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function atualizarSelect() {
        console.log('test');
    }
</script>
<h:form id="bcr_form_2" styleClass="form">
    <div class="buttons">
        <p:commandButton id="js" onclick="atualizarSelect()" value="#{msg['btn-save']}" />
    </div>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Really tested again in debug mode in Firexo he enters the `update()` remoteCommand , but in Chrome does not.

Comment: Did you try to remove `remoteCommand` and move `actionListener` attribute to save `commandButton` and remove `update()` from js code?

Comment: I changed the code and it's working well `<p:commandButton action="#{veiculoBean.updateModal()}" value="#{msg['btn-save']}">
     <p:ajax oncomplete="atualizarSelect();"> </p:ajax>
    </p:commandButton>  ` however I can not update the component via javascript this is actually the id generated for it. After the call to the precise remoteCommand update a selectOneMenu currently update with F5 in the browser want to do this via javascript.

Comment: I didn't understand. Could you explain better? Do you want update a `selectOneMenu`?